# Problema con relación muchos a muchos entity framework + PrimaryKey Combinado

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Saludos estoy teniendo inconvenientes con una relación Mucho a Mucho con foreignkeys compuesto.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class Empleado
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [StringLength(100)]
   public string Nombre { get; set; }

   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public int? IdentificacionId { get; set; }
   public Identificacion Identificacion { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [StringLength(11)]
   [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
   public string NoIdentificacion { get; set; }
}

// Entidad relación
public class EmpleadoNomina
{
   public int EmpleadoId { get; set; }
   public int NominaId { get; set; }
   public decimal Salario { get; set; }
   public int DescuentoLey { get; set; }
   public decimal? SalarioIngresoEgreso { get; set; }

   public Nomina Nomina { get; set; }
   public Empleado Empleado { get; set; }
}

// FluentApi
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // Constraint combinado TipoId + NoID
   modelBuilder.Entity<Empleado>().HasKey(x => new { x.IdentificacionId, x.NoIdentificacion });

   // Relación
   modelBuilder.Entity<EmpleadoNomina>().HasKey(k => new { k.NominaId, k.EmpleadoId });
}
```

El problema surge cuando se crea la tabla de la relación. 
A esta se le agregan las columnas Empleado_IdentificacionId, Empleado_NoIdentificacion. Y la columna EmpleadoId sin foreignkey.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El otro problema es que al buscar en la DB tengo con esto no puedo usar .Find(id);
ejemplo: db.Empleados.Find(15); Esto da error ya que me exige pasar las tres keys.

La relación solo quiero hacerla por EmpleadoId y que se remuevan las columnas Empleado_IdentificacionId, Empleado_NoIdentificacion.

Comment: Veo un par de cosas por corregir, la primera es que es recomendable poner el mismo nombre al objeto que su tipo, por ejemplo `public Nomina Nomina { get; set; }`, el tipo de dato es `Nomina` y el nombre del objeto se llama igual `Nomina`. Otro es que siendo el número de nómina un identificador único, no veo necesario crear `NominaId`, dado esto, el `EmpleadoId` ya no es necesario y por lo tanto la relación simplifica la búsqueda. Además de que no se requieren dos modelos, en uno solo pueden ir todos los datos del empleado, eso simplifica aún más la problemática.

Comment: Disculpa hermano pero no te entendí.

Comment: Básicamente me refiero a que tienes dos clases, una `Empleado` y la otra `EmpleadoNomina` lo cual no es necesario, en la clase o modelo `Empleado` puedes poner toda la información necesaria, con eso mitigas el problema de relaciones que tienes.

Comment: Creo que estas confundido la clase EmpleadoNomina es la clase de la relacion ya que es de muchos a muchos. Una Nomina puede tener muchos empleados y un empleado pueden pertenecer a varias nominas

Comment: Bueno, todo depende a lo que llames nómina. Yo tengo el entendido que una nómina es un empleado, es posible que estemos hablando de cosas diferentes por eso no lo había entendido

Comment: Una nomina contiene un grupo de empleados los cuales son las personas que cobran en dicha nomina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo resolví con Index Dataanotations para crear el Index Único Compuesto en lugar de primary key compuesto(este era el responsable de mi problema).

Eliminé las claves compuestas de la clase principal y agregué una lista de EmpleadoNomina a las dos clases de entidades.

Cambié todo por como se ve a continuación y ahora está funcionando muy bien. Esto lo que quise hacer desde el principio.

```
// Class 2
public class Empleado
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [StringLength(100)]
   public string Nombre { get; set; }

   [Index("IX_Identificacion", 1, IsUnique = true)]
   public int? IdentificacionId { get; set; }
   public Identificacion Identificacion { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [StringLength(11)]
   [Index("IX_Identificacion", 2, IsUnique = true)]
   public string NoIdentificacion { get; set; }

   public List<EmpleadoNomina> EmpleadoNominas { get; set; }
}

// Class 1
public class Nomina
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [StringLength(200)]
   public string Descripcion { get; set; }

   public int Frecuencia { get; set; }

   public int Dia { get; set; }

   public List<EmpleadoNomina> EmpleadoNominas { get; set; }
}

// Relation Entity (Table)
public class EmpleadoNomina
{
   public int EmpleadoId { get; set; }
   public int NominaId { get; set; }
   public decimal Salario { get; set; }
   public int DescuentoLey { get; set; }
   public decimal? SalarioIngresoEgreso { get; set; }

   public Nomina Nomina { get; set; }
   public Empleado Empleado { get; set; }
}

// FluentApi
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // Nominas -> Empleados
   modelBuilder.Entity<EmpleadoNomina>().HasKey(k => new { k.NominaId, k.EmpleadoId });
   modelBuilder.Entity<EmpleadoNomina>().HasRequired(e => e.Empleado).WithMany(n => n.EmpleadoNominas).HasForeignKey(r => r.EmpleadoId);
   modelBuilder.Entity<EmpleadoNomina>().HasRequired(n => n.Nomina).WithMany(n => n.EmpleadoNominas).HasForeignKey(n => n.NominaId);
}
```

Es lo que siempre quise hacer. gracias por todo

[image]